# Counting specific permutations

Tags: combinatorics

What is the reasoning behind the solution to the following problem: Consider the set of nine-digit numbers that can be formed by rearranging the integers $1$ through $9$ without repetition. Find the number of permutations for which the $1$ and the $2$ precede the $3$ and the $4$.

The author relates this problem to a simpler one: finding the number of permutations of the integers $1$ through $4$ for which the $1$ and the $2$ precede the $3$ and the $4$. I know that of the 4!=24 permutations, only four (1,2,3,4),(1,2,4,3),(2,1,3,4),(2,1,4,3) have the required property. But why is it that $\frac{4}{24}$ of the 9! permutations satisfy the condition imposed on $1,2,3,$ and $4$? Why is the number of permutations where $1$ and $2$ precede $3$ and $4$ equal to $\frac{4}{24} \cdot 9!$?

Comment: Because the other digits can be intermingled any which way, the conditions imposed will remain met.

Answer (score 1):

You already have found all permutations $\tau \in \mathfrak{S}_4$ that verify $\max(\tau(1),\tau(2)) < \min(\tau(3),\tau(4))$, let us call $A$ this set of permutations.

You can show that for each $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_9$ verifying this same property, there exists $\tau \in A$, $\varphi:\{1,\dots,4\} \rightarrow \{1,\dots,9\}$, strictly increasing, such that $\sigma_{|\{1,\dots,4\}} = \varphi \circ \tau$ and these are unique.

You then just need to find the image of the $9-4 = 5$ digits remaining for $\sigma$, for which there are only $5$ places possible, it is thus equivalent to chose a permutation $\pi \in  \mathfrak{S}_5$ to fit these remaining digits.

In summary, your set $B \subset \mathfrak{S}_9$ of permutation verifying this property is isomorphic to the set $A  \times [4,9] \times \mathfrak{S}_5$, where $[4,9]$ is the set of strictly increasing functions from $\{1,\dots,4\}$ to $\{1,\dots,9\}$.

We can now compute
$$\sharp B = \sharp A  \cdot \sharp [4,9] \cdot \cdot \sharp \mathfrak{S}_5 = 4 \cdot \binom{9}{4} \cdot5! = \frac{9!}{3!} = \frac{1}{6} 9!$$
which is what you wished to find.

If you take the same problem with $n$ instead of $9$, you will find
$$ B \simeq A  \times [4,n] \times \mathfrak{S}_{n-4} $$
So
$$\sharp B = 4  \cdot \binom{n}{4} \cdot (n-4)! = \frac{1}{6} n!$$
which means for each size of permutation you consider, you'll always have one sixth that verify this property.

You could even wonder what would happen if you chose to have $p$ and $q$ two integers such that $p+q \leqslant n$ such that $\max_{i\leqslant p} \sigma(i) < \min_{p<j\leqslant p+q} \sigma(j)$ as a constraint. If the set $A$ plays the same role in $\mathfrak{S}_{p+q}$, you will find exactly $p! \cdot q!$ permutations $\tau$ in $A$ (the first $p$ go to the first $p$ and the last $q$ to the last $q$).

Then you will get
$$ B \simeq A  \times [p+q,n] \times \mathfrak{S}_{n-(p+q)} $$
So
$$\sharp B = p!q!  \cdot \binom{n}{p+q} \cdot (n-(p+q))! = \frac{p! q!}{(p+q)!} n! = \frac{n!}{\binom{p+q}{p}}$$

Maybe you can show that $A$ is a subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_4$, it is commonly written as $V_4$.